# IEnumerable<SPListItem>and LINQ Error

Tags: 2013, development, linq, exception

In the following code, the "FirstOrDefault" function returns a SPlistItem; it **is** a valid item.  However, the "ToList" function throws an exception of "System.NullReferenceException".

Why does FirstOrDefault return a item, that is part of the set I am looking for, but ToList throws an exception?

```
List<SPListItem> allRecords = get_All_Records();

IEnumerable<SPListItem> results = allRecords.Where(item=>item["key"].ToString() == "4993d76a-9ae4-492b-baab-a9a6e33a3661");

String temp = results.FirstOrDefault()["value"].ToString(); //This line gives one of the items that I am looking for.

List<SPListItem> subSet = results.ToList(); //This line throws exception.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the items in allRecords is null.  Because FirstOrDefault only accesses the first item, a valid item is returned.  When ToList is called, it accesses **all** the record and the condition causes an error when it gets to the null record.
The following is the solution:

```
IEnumerable<SPListItem> results = allRecords.Where(item=>
  item !=null && item["key"].ToString() == "4993d76a-9ae4-492b-baab-a9a6e33a3661");
```

Comment: Hi @amsackett If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors. Thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: The forum made me wait to accept the answer.

Comment: yes it's 2 days if it's your answer